# When i add a JavaScript element to my SVG file it disapears

Tags: javascript, html, css, snap.svg, inkscape

I am using snapsvg to manipulate my SVG file created with Inkscape. 
When i try to add a rectangle from snapsvg to my already existing svg i get a blank page. You can see a example how i manipulate the svg.

I tried to make a new script section but it always but the rectangle or the element  either above or under my svg. And i want it to be inside my svg.

```
//Run script right away

window.onload = function () {
var s = Snap("#iconDiv");

//Load SVG file

Snap.load("lager2.svg", function(f) {

//Load Rectangles and elements

Element1 = f.select("#Element1");
Group1 = f.select("#Group1");


//manipulate my rectangle
 Group1.hover(function() {
    Element1.attr({
     fill: "red"
    });
 });
});
}
```

The only error message that i get is this one:

**Uncaught TypeError: s.circle is not a function
    at window.onload**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't add elements with SnapSVG to my Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57669118/cant-add-elements-with-snapsvg-to-my-page)

Answer (score 0):

Is the element `#iconDiv` a `div`, as the name suggests?

The [getting started](http://snapsvg.io/start/) docs for Snap.svg says

> First lets create our drawing surface out of existing SVG element

So you need to change your line of code accordingly:

```js
var s = Snap("#iconDiv"); // Target a <div> won't work
```

to

```js
var s = Snap("#iconSvg"); // Target the <svg> element instead
```

Comment: I have the drawing surface just didn't post the code for it                                   <body>                    
<div id="iconDiv"></div>
    </body>

Comment: As I understand, Snap.svg must have an actual `<svg>` element to function. Where in your code is the element you are trying to add the rectangle to?

Comment: It is not there the code i posted is completly working. It is loading my SVG and it animates it but when i want to add a circle for example like this: ```var bigCircle = s.circle(150, 150, 100); ``` . Everything disappears. The only way i can add the circle is by creating a new script area but then it is over or under my SVG and i want to get it into my svg .

Comment: Perhaps it is related to how you structure/nest the svg elements? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935631/how-to-append-an-element-inside-another-on-snapsvg, perhaps it is related to the same question.

Comment: nah does not help me at all