# Can't add elements with SnapSVG to my Page

Tags: javascript, html, css, snap.svg, inkscape

So I am using SnapSVG to manipulate (animate) my SVG File that i created with Inkscape. The animating of the different elements like a rectangle or circle is working completely fine. The problem that i have is when i try to add a new element like a rectangle with SnapSVG code it does not work and the whole screen is blank (everything disappears). Why do i have this problem? Is it even possible to add a new element with SnapSVG to a existing SVG File?

Down below i showed you some code on how i manipulate the SVG and how it gets displayed in a DIV on my Page. And I am also showing you how I am trying to add a new Element with SnapSVG

I tried almost everything. I can put the code for the new Element outside of the code for the already existing SVG but then it always appears outside of the SVG file.

```
  <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Inkscape Animated Icon Snap</title>
<!--We need to add the Snap.svg script to our document-->
        <script src="snap.svg.js"></script>
        <script>
//Run script right away
            window.onload = function () {
//We'll be appending the icon to this DIV later
                var s = Snap("#svgDiv");
//Have Snap load the SVG file
                Snap.load("icon.svg", function(f) {
                    s.append(f);
//Assign the white rectangle
                    whiteRect = f.select("#whiteRect");

//Assign the whole icon group
                    icon = f.select("#icon");

                    //When the icon is hovered over, have the white rectangle move up slightly with elastic properties
                    icon.hover(function() {

                        whiteRect.animate({y:18}, 500, mina.elastic);
                    },
//And return to original position when not hovered over
                               function() {
                        whiteRect.animate({y:23.984177}, 500, mina.elastic);
                    }
                    );

                    var bigCircle = s.circle(0, 0, 20).attr({fill: 'green' });
            icon.append(bigCircle);
//Finally append the icon to iconDiv in the body

                });          
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
<!--Here's the DIV that will hold the animated SVG icon-->
<svg id="svgDiv"></svg>     
    </body>
```

So basically what I want as a result is just another rectangle added to my SVG File. What i get is a blank Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 main things spring to mind (hard to be sure without the html/svg as well).

Firstly, you Snap must be called on an SVG element, not an HTML element, so when I see this line...

```
var s = Snap("#iconDiv");
```

it's almost certainly wrong. It cannot be a div, or any HTML element. Snap works on SVG elements,

```
var s = Snap("#anSVGselement");
```

is what's needed.

Secondly, your line

```
s.append(f);
```

Wants to be straight after the Snap.load()

```
Snap.load("icon.svg", function(f) {
    // stuff here probably won't work, there are some minimal methods like select, but not like hover etc
    s.append(f);
    //do stuff now it's appended
    var icon = s.select("#icon");
    var bigCircle = s.circle(10, 970, 20);
    icon.append(bigCircle);
});
```

The problem is, f is just a fragment at this point, it has no place in the DOM yet, so methods like 'hover' etc, aren't available until you have added with append into the DOM. Once it's appended these methods become available. There are a few methods available like select, before it's appended (so you 'may' be able to select an element from the fragment and then append that, rather than appending everything I think).

[Example](http://svg.dabbles.info/test/so.html)

Also note, the icon.svg file has some transforms on it, so you will need to adjust the circle to have the correct cx/cy like in my example, or add a transform to match (or remove the transforms from the original svg and have correct cx/cy)

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem. Stuff like 'hover' is working completely fine!!!! I just want to add a new element like a rectangle for example this circle ```var bigCircle = s.circle(150, 150, 100);```

Comment: If you want to solve the problem, first you have to use code that is correct in the first place. Just because something somehow works in the first place, does not mean that it's correct and won't cause other problems. So correct that first.

Comment: can you maybe answer by editing my whole code so it is right just so we dont have any misunderstandings

Comment: ok so now animations are still working even doe i put the s.append(f); under the snap.load so that nice. Now i don't get what you want me to do with the ```var s = Snap("#iconDiv")```

Comment: I think we need to see the html and the svg in the file somehow. Basically the problem with "#iconDiv" is that Snap doesn't work with a Div. So, either it's just mislabelled, and it's actually an svg and not a div, or something else is happening. This maybe a redherring, but it's worth clarifying what iconDiv actually is. This probably isn't the actual issue, but it's just worth getting rid of any issues clouding the problem first. See if you can include the html/svg. The you "may" be able to do something like s.select('#someSvgOrGroupElement").append(s.rect(10,10,10,10)) or similar.

Comment: the script above is the whole html file. I asked this question based on this tutorial here.http://goinkscape.com/how-to-animate-icons-with-inkscape-and-snap-svg/

Comment: Ok, that tutorial has quite a few mistakes in different places, maybe you're lucky with a version of Snap that handles that, but typically it won't work with a div. For completeness, I would change iconDiv to iconSvg and change the div tag to an svg tag. Then the remaining bit is, what IS  icon.svg (especially what #icon is)..we need to see the contents of that file. If it's just a circle for example, you can't add a rect to a circle. If it has a transform, it could be that you are adding a rect and it's appeared off the screen.

Comment: So the icon.svg is just my SVG file with the 2 rectangles from the tutorial that i linked you. And #icon is the id of the group of the 2 rectangles (blue and white). I edited the div to a svg and now it shows a blank page. Can you maybe try the tutorial by yourself and change it so you can add a rectangle to it or a circle i think that would safe us a lot of time :D.

Comment: Ok, so you need to include the code where you add the rect to the group #icon

Comment: I am creating the group in Inkscape and not with code

Comment: Your question states that you have a problem adding a rect with Snap....where is the code for this ?

Comment: as i said above i have a svg file with 2 rectangles and i am manipulating them with snapsvg and now i want to add a circle like this ```var bigCircle = s.circle(150, 150, 100);``` to the svg file

Comment: So in that case it would be icon.append(bigCircle) (inside the load function)

Comment: ok and where do i add this code? at the other var? ```var bigCircle = s.circle(150, 150, 100);```

Comment: have added it to the answer (just edited, so refresh)

Comment: we have a problem. I have to put the s.append(f); under all the f.selects otherwise the animations are not working. And when i add the circle, everything just gets blank.

Comment: and just so you know changing the div to a svg also makes everything disapear

Comment: thanks man can you somehow link me this file? or give me a download link for google drive?

Comment: so i don't know what I am doing wrong :(. I saved your and opened it and nothing is working. I am getting a error message " Cannot read property 'hover' of null

Comment: Check you have the same named snap file that you are loading in, eg snap.svg.js or snap.svg.min.js etc (mine was slightly different), things like that.

Comment: yeah i checked that at the moment it is only loading the 2 rectangles. Also if i go into the console in the browser it still says ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hover' of null``` . The circle is not showing up aswell. And how can i make the svg (body) bigger?

Comment: The svg icon file, has a width/height and viewbox defined, you can edit those, and I think it will make it bigger (refresh my test link above). I don't know above your hover issue without seeing what code you currently have that's different to mine.

Comment: Does not work with changing the width and height of the viewbox. I changed the whole code of my question so you can see my current code. I think it is the same as yours. and the snap.svg.js file should also be the right one since i saved yours and i am usign that one

Comment: it is also giving me some errors in the snap.svg.js file but i don't think they matter a lot

Comment: You need to include your icon.svg as well, and you need to be specific rather than "does not work"...what doesn't work.

Comment: where and how do i need to include my icon.svg ? I managed to change the size of the viewbox.

Comment: I mean include the contents in the original question, and update it there if you change it.

Comment: isn't it getting included with the Snap.load ("icon.svg") ?. And at the moment it is loading up the 2 rectangles and i get the same error that it Cannot read property 'hover' of null. The circle is also not showing up but i don't get any error for that. Since it can't read the hover the animation is also not working.

Comment: Works for me, so you need to figure a way to isolate it. Chances are if it's saying it cannot read property of null, it's not loading in the file or can't find the dom object. So either the filename is wrong, it's inacessible, the id is incorrect or something else, or it's not added correct. Check the console for other errors first.

Comment: what did you use to create the svg? can it be a problem with the svg file itself? and i am getting some other errors in the snap.svg.js file

Comment: I used the one in that tutorial and just created a local file. Make sure the html/js code can access it ok if it's on a server or whatever.

Comment: yeah hosting a server with xampp i hope thats ok

Comment: DAMN it is working now i had to put the s.append(f) under the icon.append(bigCircle). You said that is wrong but somehow it is working for me

Comment: With append I don't think it should make any difference in this particular case (some methods it does make a difference for though)